# Issue in new CLI command, package version create

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, salesforcedx-cli, 2gp

After updating to the new CLI version, unable to create new package version.

I am not getting any error, in a few seconds it's saying as created but actually it's not creating anything.

[image]

Let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I missed a meta.XML file, CLI will not throw any error if your component is missing a meta.XML file.

If any of you faces the same problem, try to push your code in the new scratch org and see whether you are getting any errors.